# Expected behavior FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm testing a rake task - `update_city_status_for_users`:

```
task update_city_status_for_users: :environment do
    User.update_city_statuses do |user, new_status|
        # does something
    end
end
```

Method `User.update_city_statuses`:

```
def self.update_city_statuses(&block)
    users_ids = Journey.valid.where.not(user_id: nil).pluck(:user_id) # Only journeys (valid) for route 1
    users_with_journeys = self.where(id: users_ids)

    Rails.logger.info "Only update users with at least one journey: #{users_with_journeys.count} users to update."

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      users_with_journeys.each do |u|
            new_status = u.new_status? 
            if new_status != nil
                begin
                    u.update!(city_status: new_status)
                    yield(u,new_status) if block_given?
                rescue => exception
                    Rails.logger.error "Exception updating user with id #{u.id}. Exception: "+exception.to_s
                end
            end
        end
    end
  end
```

And this is the test:

```
RSpec.describe do 
    describe "update_city_status_for_users" do
        it 'updates users with their corespondent new city status: from nil to "Venice"' do

            user = user_with_journeys(5, "Venice")
            city_status_before_task = user.city_status

            BicycleIsland::Application.load_tasks
            Rake::Task['update_city_status_for_users'].invoke

            expect(city_status_before_task).to eq nil
            expect(user.city_status).to be_an_instance_of CityStatus
            expect(user.city_status.city).to eq "Venice"
        end
    end
end
```

`user_with_journeys` is defined where the user factories are and basically it creates a user with 5 journeys.

After task invocation inside the test I check the user variable (factory created):

```
user.city_status 
# nil
```

However, when I pull the user from the database the association has been made and city_status is not nil:

```
User.find(user.id).city_status 
# #<CityStatus id: 6, level: 6, city: "Venice", distance: 1730, created_at: "2020-11-18 17:11:32", updated_at: "2020-11-18 17:11:32", image_file_name: "Venice-1000.png">
```

Both users are the same:

```
User.find(user.id) == user
# true
```

However, the city_status is not associated when calling the factory directly. That's not the behavior I was expecting. I would expect to carry on the updates and associations that have been made.

I'm probably missing something? Could anyone help me to point it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails caches the model instances to avoid repetitive database queries. You'll need to call

```
user.reload
```

before your assertions to update the object with the latest values from the database.

Comment: However, if I define user as let(:user) outside the example user.reload doesn't work. Any chance you know the reason? Thanks.